# Arduino UDP receiving combined ASCII and hex code

Tags: arduino, udp

I am currently working on a larger LEDCube project, a component of which is getting it to be talked to over UDP so its colours can be set on the fly. For this, I made a UDP packet layout of the following commands:

mode:#

reset

data:HEX

The issue I am facing is that the data command draws gibberish when it should really be drawing nothing. Passing 00 00 00 in results in a technicolour cube, and not black.

Code snippet of UDP decoding below.

```
void processUDPPacket(){
int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
if (packetSize) {
  if(DEBUG){
  Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
  Serial.println(packetSize);
  Serial.print("From ");
  IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
  Serial.print(remoteIp);
  Serial.print(", port ");
  Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());
}
// read the packet into packetBufffer
int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);
if (len > 0) {
  packetBuffer[len] = 0;
}




if(DEBUG){
  Serial.println("Contents:");
  Serial.println(packetBuffer);
  for(int i = 0; i< 255; i++){
    Serial.print((int)packetBuffer[i],HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}


char *command  = strtok(packetBuffer,":"); //pointer to array containing command word
char *payload = strtok(NULL,":"); //pointer to array containing payload 


if(strcmp(command,"mode")==0){
    mode = atoi(payload); //char array to int
    modeSelect();
  }

if(mode == MODE_UDP){
  //command is reset, reset
  if(strcmp(command,"reset")==0){
    reset();
  }
  else if(strcmp(command,"data")==0){

    for(int i = 0; i< NUM_LEDs; i++){
      int r = payload[3*i + 0];
      int g = payload[3*i + 1];
      int b = payload[3*i + 2];
      rCurr[i] = map(r, 0,255, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
      gCurr[i] = map(g, 0,255, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
      bCurr[i] = map(b, 0,255, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
      
      if(DEBUG){
        Serial.print(r);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(g);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.println(b);
      }
    }
  }

}

// send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
Udp.endPacket();
}
}
```

Writeback works fine, but that is just string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try and work out why the string tokenizer would not work on binary containing a bunch of null characters (that probably is the problem), I removed the strtok completely and have data checks run on the individual characters using memcmp. See new code below

```
void processUDPPacket(){
int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
if (packetSize) {
if(DEBUG){
  Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
  Serial.println(packetSize);
  Serial.print("From ");
  IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
  Serial.print(remoteIp);
  Serial.print(", port ");
  Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());
}
// read the packet into packetBufffer
for(int i = 0; i< 256; i++){
  packetBuffer[i] = 0;
}
int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);





if(DEBUG){
  Serial.println("Contents:");
  Serial.println(packetBuffer);
  for(int i = 0; i< 255; i++){
    Serial.print((int)packetBuffer[i],HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

if(memcmp(packetBuffer,"mode",4)==0){
    Serial.println((int)packetBuffer[4] - '0');
    mode = (int)packetBuffer[4] - '0'; //char array to int
    modeSelect();
  }

if(mode == MODE_UDP){
  //command is reset, reset
  if(memcmp(packetBuffer,"reset",5)==0){
    reset();
  }
  else if(memcmp(packetBuffer,"data",4)==0){

    for(int i = 0; i< NUM_LEDs; i++){
      int r = packetBuffer[4+3*i + 0];
      int g = packetBuffer[4+3*i + 1];
      int b = packetBuffer[4+3*i + 2];
      rCurr[i] = map(r, 0,255, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
      gCurr[i] = map(g, 0,255, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
      bCurr[i] = map(b, 0,255, 0, MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
      
      if(DEBUG){
        Serial.print(r);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(g);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.println(b);
      }
    }
  }

}

// send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
Udp.endPacket();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

1. If you are going to send a string representation of a numeric value, it will be easier to better to represent the value as decimal than hex, this is because there is no readily available function (in standard library, at least not in the form that you are formatting it) to convert a string of hex to integer, but it is very easy to convert a string of decimal to integer.
2. A numeric value of 0 or 32, when converted to string, it often became "0" or "32", that is the length of the string will vary depend on the numeric value, so if you pack three values of 0, 32, and 255 together like "032255", you have no idea where the first value end, it is therefore often to have a *delimiter* to separate the values.

I would therefore suggest that you consider to change your protocol to send the value with a delimiter, a 'space' would do, so that you can parse the data with `strtok()` easily.

Now for your code, if your packetBuffer received "mode:# reset data:0 32 255", the `char *payload = strtok(NULL,":");` does not give the payload, it gives the things that you don't want " reset data", always print out data when you doing debugging.

Once you get the string of the payload, you can continue to use `strtok(payload, ' ');` to parse the `payload` into 3 integer values.

Here is example of the code:

```cpp
char packetBuffer[]{"mode:# reset data:0 32 125"};

char *command  = strtok(packetBuffer,":");  // get the "mode"
strtok(NULL, ":");                          // ignore the "# reset data"
char *payload = strtok(NULL,":");           // get the payload

uint8_t r = atoi(strtok(payload, " "));
uint8_t g = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
uint8_t b = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));

if (DEBUG){
  Serial.print(r);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(g);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(b);
}
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting above, can you take a look at what the problem could be again? There are 3 different commands. The first 2 work, the data:000000 does not

Comment: So the "000000" is the string representation of the hex value of R, G, B?

Comment: yes it is the representation of RGB

Comment: I have two suggestions, and I updated my answers to include those suggestions, please take a look.

Comment: I noticed that you post a different approach as your answer, there is no right or wrong answer, there are many ways to achieve the same thing, it just which way make the code simpler and easier to maintain/read. Clearly using string to represent a set of data is not the best efficient way (RGB values can be represented in 3 bytes while a string representation of it is at least 6 bytes. Personal I prefer to use a struct and send with a mixture of string(for command) and binary (for data), but that's a separate subject.